# how to send and receive messages through android phone connected to pc

Tags: android-emulator

how to send and receive messages through android phone connected to pc.The application is created using eclipse. When sending option done through emulator the message must be sent from the connected phone.As i'm new in android anyone please help me out.

Thanks......

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the emulator and not the real phone, you can follow the given steps:

open a console
connect via telnet to the running emulator: telnet localhost 5554 (you can find the portnumber in the title of the emulator)
type this: sms send senderPhoneNumber textmessage

Otherwise, check the link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=act.main#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDUwMSwiYWN0Lm1haW4iXQ..